# Downloading all the Maven dependenies

Tags: maven, build, dependencies, offline

I have a Maven project with lots of Maven dependencies listed in the POM file. The computer which I need to build the application on missing any Internet connection because of security reasons.

Is there a way to download all dependencies with Maven to a local directory on a computer with Internet. Then copy these to the offline-computer, and modify the POM file to build by using this local directory where all the dependencies are. Does this sound possible to you? Is there a better or smarter way? Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Use a repository manager which is used on the internal computer...

Comment: I would download everything on the pc with the internet, migrate that local repository to the offline computer and then do an offline maven update.